# How do i create the second and third row in flutter UI?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been having this challenge and I really need your help. I am building the UI of the attached image but I am finding it difficult to develop it further. I was able to develop it upto the first row but i need help to get 2 other rows. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

```html
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
              child: Image.asset('images/learn.png', height: 80.0),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
              child: Image.asset('images/ambulance.png', height: 80.0),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
              child: Image.asset('images/responder.png', height: 80.0),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),      
    );
   
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: if these menu name and images are comes from api,i suggest you can use [Gridview][1],if it is not you can use table refer answer of "Kamil Poniewierski"@Dennis
For grid view check following link `https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/grid-lists`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I recommend you to use Listview widget. Please check the link the video and documentation give you an idea.[Listview Flutter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

ListView is okay but you may want to just wrap your Row with Column, or even better - use [Table](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html).

Comment: Thank you very muc. This table might be what i am looking for. Let me look at it and see how it works.